# Python - How to import modules for unit testing?

Tags: python, unit-testing, import, nose

I have some functions in a module (mod1). I want to run some unit tests (specifically nosetests) on them. Most of the introductions to using unittest/nosetests that I've seen seem to just import the code to test using `from mod1 import func1`. However, from what I gather, I want to avoid importing any code from modules (mod2) imported by the mod1, so that you're only testing the code directly in the mod1. Instead I should be mocking the functions from mod2 which mod1 imported. Am I just being silly and `from mod1 import func1` will not import the code from mod2? Or is there some other way to import func1 so that it doesn't import any code from mod2? Thank you much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your design decision than m1 interacts wit m2 so you have options

```
1) Test mod1 with mod2
2) Mock functions in mo2d
```

However there are some ways do avoid direct imports check out this code

```
https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/loading.py
https://github.com/tangentlabs/django-oscar/blob/master/oscar/core/loading.py
```

hope that could help you to separate your modules a bit(if it is really needed)

Comment: So by "Mock functions in mod2" do you mean that I just import mod1 which in turn imports mod2, and then I just mock each function being imported by mod2 so that none of them are actually used? Is there some way to insure that each of them has been mocked and none of the real functions will be used?

Comment: When running your test framework there must be a a method something like "setubStubs" we have in unintest2. Here is right place to place this code. And this thing http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/index.html# could be useful